# I want to draw block diagrams,what's wrong?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the circuits below, however, the code doesn't work. would someone help me?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbComp{a}{E}
    \sbBloc{b}{$H_1$}{a}
            \sbRelier[$E_1$]{E}{a}
    \sbBlocL{c}{$H_2$}{b}
            \sbRelier[$\epsilon$]{a}{b}
    \sbComph{d}{c}
            \sbRelier[u]{c}{d}
    \sbBlocL{e}{$H_3$}{d}
    \sbBlocL{f}{$H_4$}{e}
    \sbSortie[5]{S1}{f}
            \sbRelier{f}{S1}
            \sbNomLien[0.8]{S1}{$S_1$}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[-4]{f}{u}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy{e}{v}
    \sbBlocr{r1}{$R_1$}{u}
    \sbBlocr{r2}{$R_2$}{v}
    \sbBlocrL{r3}{$R_3$}{r2}
    \sbRelieryx{f-S1}{r1}
    \sbRelierxy[n1]{r1}{d}
    \sbRelieryx{e-f}{r2}
    \sbRelierxy[n2]{r3}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: None of the `\sb...` commands is defined...

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the `schemabloc` package<sup>[1](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/schemabloc/)</sup>:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{schemabloc}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
```

Comment: thanks,I tried it, however there is still error says "please type another file name",why?

Comment: You probably need to download and install that package first. (The download link can be found on the referenced page on texample.net)

Comment: @sweetyBaby usually that error comes when you try to overwrite the pdf and in the meanwhile you visualize it with adobe reader. This reader doesn't allow to overwrite files while open, so close your file before compiling or use a viewer that allows that (SumatraPDF on Windows)

Comment: @Spike in fact I don't use any viewer or visualize it when I compiling the file~~

Comment: @sweetyBaby And what happens if you just press ENTER when the compilation stops? Anyway, I think that you should edit the first post and report the useful part of the .log file

Comment: you can download here http://sciences-indus-cpge.papanicola.info/Schema-blocs-avec-PGF-TIKZ-sous or http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/schemabloc/